# PUTTY -m ,but waiting for terminal to iddle

Tags: linux, putty, raspberry-pi, serial

from an ubuntu VM I try to putty to a reaspberry by through uart pins and an FTDI dongle

I want to automate the upload of a text file

I use :

```
sudo putty -serial /dev/ttyUSB0 -sercfg 115200,8,n,1,N -m somefile.txt
```

it works but the raspberry pi first need to initialize, sending some text
**but putty does not way for that**

is there a way with putty to

- reset the RPI
- **wait for the serial prompt**
- then send the file
- exit putty

thanks

edit :

I now use this so far :

```
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
exec 99<>/dev/ttyUSB0
read answer <&99
read answer <&99
read answer <&99
read answer <&99
cat some.txt >&99
exec 99>&-
```

Comment: I believe that `-m` switch does not even work with serial ports (it's for SSH only). Anyway, use `plink` with an input redirection. That will allow you to delay the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is important to use bash and file descriptors between 4 and 9 (afaik)

the read lines are there to read prompt lines from the other side of the terminal

```
!#\bin\bash
stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
exec 9<>/dev/ttyUSB0
read answer <&9
read answer <&9
read answer <&9
read answer <&9
cat some.txt >&9
exec 9>&-
```